# Find an MVUE for a random sample based on a given probability density function

Tags: statistics

Let $Y_1,...,Y_n$ denote a random sample from the probability density function
$$
f(y)=\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
(\theta y)^{\theta-1}, \space \space \space for \space 0<y<1 \\
0, \space \space \space \space elsewhere \\
\end{array}
\right. 
$$
for some $\theta > 0$. Find an MVUE for $\theta$ based on $U=\prod_{i=1}^nY_i$. You must first prove that $U$ is a sufficient statistic.

I am stuck on how to prove that $U$ is a sufficient statistic, I was given the hint to use $-ln U=-ln\prod^n_{i=1}Y_i=\sum^n_{i=1}-lnY$, but I was wondering if there was an easier and more straight forward way of proving that $U$ is a sufficient statistic.

Comment: Where did you get stuck? Has you proved that $U$ is sufficient statistics? Show us some effort please!

Comment: Hi, welcome to Math.SE. Please indicate what you have tried and where you are stuck. This will help people better tailor their answer to your background and situation. It will also demonstrate that you are interested in your question and not just looking for someone to do your homework for you - Math.SE is not a homework site.

Comment: Sorry, I have edited the question to be more specific.

Comment: The pdf is actually $\theta y^{\theta-1}$.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/484370/321264

Answer (score 0):

For a sample $\boldsymbol y = (y_1, \ldots, y_n)$, the joint density of the sample given $\theta$ is $$f_{\boldsymbol Y}(\boldsymbol y \mid \theta) = \prod_{i=1}^n f_Y (y_i \mid \theta) = \prod_{i=1}^n (\theta y_i)^{\theta-1} \mathbb 1(0 \le y_i \le 1) = \theta^{n(\theta-1)} \left(\prod_{i=1}^n y_i \right)^{\theta-1} \!\!\mathbb 1(0 \le y_{(1)} \le y_{(n)} \le 1).$$  Now if $U(\boldsymbol y) = \prod_{i=1}^n y_i$ is the statistic of interest, we see that the joint density can be expressed as $$f_{\boldsymbol Y}(\boldsymbol y \mid \theta) = g(U(\boldsymbol y) \mid \theta) h(\boldsymbol y),$$ where $$g(u \mid \theta) = \theta^{n(\theta-1)} u^{\theta-1},$$ and $$h(\boldsymbol y) = \mathbb 1(0 \le y_{(1)} \le y_{(n)} \le 1).$$ This establishes that $U$ is sufficient for $\theta$ through the Factorization Theorem.